# C# Sql Column name is not valid

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = textBox1.Text;

        string s1 = comboBox1.Text;
        string s2 = comboBox2.Text;
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=D:\Desktop\DB2\DB2\Database1.sdf");
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(" update Kambariai set Klientas=[s]  Where [Kambario rūšis]=[s1]  ", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Duomenys įrašyti";
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
    }
```

[image]

I am trying to update my datatable by updating `Klientas` value with `textbox1.Text` which is made to `string = s`. It should work fine as Sql But I get an error saying that The column name is not valid `Column = s1`. `s1` shouldn't be targeted as column name it should be used as column row value.

This is outdated image Kliento ID is changed to Klientas

Comment: C# variables do not magically get into an SQL query, even if mentioned in there in brackets. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8218932/11683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("update Kambariai set Klientas="+s+"  Where [Kambario rūšis]='"+s1+"' ", conn);
```

**Analysis:**

From what you have tried, `cmd` has value like :

```
update Kambariai set Klientas=s Where [Kambario rūšis]=s1
```

From by putting proper double and single quotes around it, the value would be like:

```
update Kambariai set Klientas=1 Where [Kambario rūšis]='bar'
```

**Side Note:**

I would not recommend this method since it increases the risk of SQL injection. Use parameterized query instead.

Comment: Done as suggested above now it understands value of s1 but still it shows that it is column name.

Comment: Ok some part works it inserts value to Klientas column but the value is Klientas but textbox1.Text is not Klientas. set Klientas="'+s"' Something must be done with this part .

Comment: @GSerg: I am not a big fan of SQL injection, myself. Just trying to help OP to get what he is after. Anyway, Updated my answer.

Comment: Kliento ID is changed to Klientas read in description near Image.

Comment: @RagingBull you said you edited answer I don't see anything edited maybe you forgot to edit it?

Comment: @user3625236: Since Klientas is of type int, you don't have to use single quotes ('). See the edit.

Comment: Btw how to put multiple values in where section I try Where [Kambario rūšis]='"+s1+"', [Vietų skaičius]='"+s2"' but it shows error token ir error = =

Comment: @user3625236: You should use `AND` or `OR` instead of comma. `AND` needs both conditions to be true whereas `OR` needs only one condition to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
     SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(" update Kambariai set Klientas='" + s +"'  Where [Kambario rūšis]='" + s1 + "'", conn);
```